# How do I kill CruiseControl?

Tags: kill, cruisecontrol

I just went to run cruisecontrol only to find that it's already running when I thought it shut itself down.  For some reason I can't find the pid for cruisecontrol with ps -e in order to use kill. How can I kill this?

Comment: Implement ISpeed2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking under /my_install_path/cruisecontrol/ I found the file "cc.pid" which contains the PID that I needed to kill.

```
$ cat cc.pid
43179
$ kill 43179
```

or more succinctly

```
$ kill `cat cc.pid`
```